# Having found maximum value that belongs to area with maximums how to approximate what are the borders of that area?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

So we have found an area with at least `N` points around some center point that fit our criteria on some giant field [image] (image created with [MLDemos](http://mldemos.epfl.ch/) and paint) what are algorithms that can be used to get area borders (shown in yellow)? (area is 2d function and algorithm could not know full picture)

Comment: It looks like you want an isocontour of your function.  Do you want to represent it as a polygon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one-class SVM. LibSVM supports it.

It defines a region that contains X% of the data, where X is provided by the user. During testing, the SVM will tell you whether or not the test data is inside the region.

Comment: Will it produce one connected region?

Comment: I'm nearly certain. It is possible for it to overfit if you use bad parameters, but even then, I believe the region is still connected.